# How to position two divs "header" and "footer" around a div "content"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to position header and footer accordingly to content height.
So the header and footer are adjacent to content, even when the content size change.
I would like to know if a CSS solution exists (even CSS 3), if no a JS solution.

Notes: I cannot change the order of DIV in the HTML.
Below pictures of the desired layout.

In more details:

- I need the top side of the content positioned just after the end
  bottom side of header.
- I need the top side of the footer positioned just after the end
  bottom side of content.
- If header change height, content should move up/down.
- If content change height, footer should move up/down.

Live code: http://jsfiddle.net/wkfcnj6c/

Example is welcome :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script>
    </script>
    <style>
    #content-a, #content-b{
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
    }
    #content-a {
        background-color: red;
    }
    #content-b {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #master {
        position: absolute;
        left: 60px;
        z-index: 100;   
    }
    #header, #footer {
        width: 500px;
        height: 50px;   
    }
    #header {
        background-color: gray;
    }
    #footer {
        background-color: blue;
    }


    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="content-a">content a</div>
<div id="content-b" style="display:none">content a</div>
<div id="master">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: its unclear to me. can you please provide picture of what you're trying to achieve....

Comment: Are you stuck to that html structure? Cause if you simply put the header above and the footer beneath the content it should be default behaviour

Comment: Yes unfortunately I cannot change HTML structure :(

Comment: Pictures attached, I need the content always in the "middle" of header and footer. Thanks guys for your time on this.

Comment: I don't have time to give you a full answer, but you should check out flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/29dqk108/ using jQuery?

Comment: @Ciccolina yes this is the effect what I need, but I am looking more for CSS solution first. Thanks

Comment: I dont think this is responsive, but try it http://jsfiddle.net/fL60dygh/ css only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your html structure this isn't possible with pure css, especially with a dynamic height for the header and footer - as they are in a seperate div, it will be impossible for the content divs to know how much space is left to take up.  You would need to use js to either move your divs and calculate the heights, but I would do something along the following:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#master {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#master > div {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#master > div > div {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
```

and with the help of jquery, reorder your elements:

```
$('#master').wrapInner('<div/>');
$('#content-b').insertAfter($('#content-a').insertAfter($('#header')));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wkfcnj6c/4/)

[Example with expanded content and header](http://jsfiddle.net/wkfcnj6c/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Got it I think: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/80a6q40x/1/

What I did:
Since all is in correct order except the header, we can do this:

Remove ALL position:absolute;
Put margin-top: 50px on the content-a
Put position:ansolute; top:0px; on the #header
You may also edit the #content-a to have **min-height:** 250px; to adjust to the content in height: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/80a6q40x/4/

That's it.

```
<div id="content-a">content a</div>
<div id="content-b" style="display:none">content a</div>
<div id="master">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #content-a, #content-b{
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
    }
    #content-a {
margin-top:50px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #content-b {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #master {

        z-index: 100;   
    }
    #header, #footer {
        width: 500px;
        height: 50px;   
    }
    #header {
        background-color: gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    }
    #footer {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: No, I cannot change the HTML structure. Thanks for you time on this.

Comment: See the answer above now

Comment: Thanks, but I think with your solution If the header height will change the content won't adjust up/down because you are using margin as fix size on content.

Comment: You haven't told us that the header will change height, only the content.

Comment: I see you've added that now to your question